# Lucene/Solr Test inconsistent endOffset

Tags: testing, solr, lucene, tokenize

I'm using **BaseTokenStreamTestCase** to perform some tests... against a custom TokenFilter.

The test is failing in an inexplicable way.
You can see from my debug output, that the token it's complaining about, has an endOffset of `17`...

**inconsistent endOffset 1 pos=1 posLen=1 token=hello expected:<11> but was:<17>**

```
   original: wheel chair hello there foo bar
  increment:      1        1     1      1   
     tokens: wheel chair hello there foo bar
  positions: ----------- ----- ----- -------
    lengths:      2        1     1      2   
   sequence:      1        2     3      4   
             0123456789012345678901234567890
                      10        20        30
  start-end: 1:[0-11], 2:[12-17], 3:[18-23], 4:[24-31]
```

Heres the test code:

```
assertAnalyzesTo(analyzer, input,
        new String[] {"wheel chair", "hello", "there", "foo bar"},
        new int[] {0, 12, 18, 24},  // start offsets
        new int[] {11, 17, 23, 31}, // end offsets
        null,                       // types
        new int[] {1, 1, 1, 1},     // positionIncrement
        new int[] {2, 1, 1, 2});    // positionLength
```

Why does it think the 2nd token should end at `11` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BaseTokenStreamTestCase is generating the error from this source:
... near line 248

```
  final int endPos = pos + posLength;

  if (!posToEndOffset.containsKey(endPos)) {
    // First time we've seen a token arriving to this position:
    posToEndOffset.put(endPos, endOffset);
    //System.out.println("  + e " + endPos + " -> " + endOffset);
  } else {
    // We've seen a token arriving to this position
    // before; verify the endOffset is the same:
    //System.out.println("  + ve " + endPos + " -> " + endOffset);
    assertEquals("inconsistent endOffset " + i + " pos=" + pos + " posLen=" + posLength + " token=" + termAtt, posToEndOffset.get(endPos).intValue(), endOffset);
  }
```

Because **endPos** is calculated to be `pos + posLength` the test assumes that
`posToEndOffset.get(endPos)` will return the end position offset of the current token position + length.

This means that its reading-ahead 1 token, because the first token has a **length = 2**.
This is why the test is failing.  Length is being used improperly.

Leaving the **length attribute** set to its default of 1 corrected the test errors.